# HTML Submit -> asp response

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm fairly new to HTML and asp programming and I have occured the following problem:

When I create a simple HTML page with a submit button (as from tutorials) and a .asp script to process that submition, i just get the .asp script itself up, not the text that I submitted.

The code:

HTML code:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ASP code:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Submitted data</title>
</head>

<body>
<%
Dim name
name=Request.Form("name")
Response.Write("Name: " & name & "<br>")
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Request.QueryString("name of field") if your form has method="get".

Comment: Are you running this in Visual Studio or just from a web browser. I would think that if you are not running it from Visual Studio then it will be needed to run on a web server to process the server side code?

Comment: Out of curiosity (and serious concern), why are you using Classic ASP? The platform was made obsolete back in 2001.

Comment: `i just get the .asp script itself up` . Does it mean that you see the script code in the web browser ? if so, asp is not configured in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

filename: html_form_action.asp

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Submitted data</title>
</head>

<body>
<%
Dim name
name=Request.Form("user")
Response.Write("Name: " & name & "<br>")
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

1. I changed the form method from get to post
2. Changed Request.Form("name") to Request.Form("user") since the input text name is user

Hope it helps